# What is the proper chmod for a file

Tags: server, chmod

I want to choose the right chmod for a file, that cannot be viewed or accesed directly, but it can be send by mail from script. I have an ubuntu server (LAMP) and I am asking myself if this could be done from the same user. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let me order two of your points:

1. In order to send a file by mail the mail client needs to be able to read the file.
2. But the file may not be viewed or accessed directly [except by the mail client?]

These two points conflict. Either you maker the file accessable and or you run the mail client with different rights. Note: You **can** do that from the same user account. The rights just need to be granted to the program reading that file, preferable in such a way that the original user account cannot also grant those rights to herself.

(E.g., you could create a group 'games; and make the file or the folder it is stored in only readable(r,x) by the group games. (Think of nethack and similar setups where the user cannot change or read the shared score files on their own. Note that you will need to change the file to something like  user:games and rwx to ---xxx---. Lastly you can combine this with set group ID on excution for the program which needs to be able to read the file).

Comment: I tried with .htaccess having "Deny from all" and a php mail() function and it works, could this have any holes? Now when thinking about security, I came to the point, if someone remotely has access to php files (view+edit), he can therefore also view those "secret" files which are meant to be sent only per mail. I think I complicated it too much...

Comment: htaccess adds a webserver to the mix. (with all its advantages and disadvantages). I see nothing about webservers or PHP in the post and I did not write the answer with that in mind. You might want to [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/679680/edit) your original post if this is for a webapplication. Otherwise it seems a solution which is needlessly complex.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the permission only the user can view and access the file, use `chmod 600 filename`.

You can use `mailx` or `mail` utilities to send the email from using the same user.